# Create ArcSDE Database from ArcCatalog

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arccatalog

Is there a way to create a spatial database from ArcCatalog that also creates the ArcSDE user, repository, and service.

Basically, I am trying to do everything that the ArcSDE Post Installation does, but from ArcCatalog.

I am using version 10 of ArcCatalog and ArcSDE and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The closest you're going to get is with personal or workgroup SDE. Those editions let you create databases from ArcCatalog but you still need to run the post-install initially to set up a SQL Server Express instance. If you're using enterprise, you're stuck with the post install (or the command line tools :)).

Answer (score 0):

Footnote:
**ArcSDE 10 Service Pack 1** (released 11/11/2010)
http://downloads2.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/ArcSDE10sp1-issues.htm
fixes lots (if use other ESRI arcgis 10 software service packs must match as they share updated .dlls) ie arcgis 10 desktop should be upgraded as well.

download available from here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1687

Comment: I looked over the issues list and I didn't see anything about creating a geodatabase from ArcCatalog.

Comment: more of a notification than solution. if did a esri support ticket the first thing they would do is get you to update the software. sometimes things are fixed not list (rare but possible).